# Excel - Shift data inside a cell to the right

Tags: excel, forms, function

I'm new here and I have a problem, it may be so simple but I need a clear idea how to do this:

As you can see in the image, suppose there is a data inside cells D4:G4, then when I want to click the Add New button the data inside these cells will shift to the left as seen in the second image.

I want to know how to do the macro for this.

An early reply would be most appreciated.

Thanks guys :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share with us the code of that button

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot to include that the button has no code at all, I know only some basic functions for excel, but working with macros is new to me so I went here to ask what would be best macro for the button, I searched the web already but I can't find my problem. :)

Comment: Its a simple switch of cell values. Have a look at the help of property 'Cells', and you will find the solution.

Comment: can you help me get some starting code for it so that I could tweak it and do the code for me, to be honest I'm not even a programmer, and macros is very new to me, :) a help would be really much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really quick way you could do it:

edit: Per comments,

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Dim x&

Set rng = Range("D4:G7")

rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Value

For x = 1 To rng.Count Step (rng.Count / rng.Columns.Count)
    rng.Item(x).Clear
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: @JayFronteras - I just noticed that my code will shift all the text over one.  In your example, the "right most"  value gets cut off when moving. If this is correct, I think if you also add `rng.Item(rng.Count).Clear` it'll remove that one as well.

Comment: thanks Bruce! the code did work nicely, I can tweak it now to work it perfectly to what I really want it. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Bruce, how about if there's also datas in other cells, can I also shift that together with the example I gave?

Comment: @JayFronteras - Do you mean if the data goes from D4 to say Z4? And you want to shift that? Yeah, just change the `Set rng = Range()` to the range you want to do.

Comment: what I mean is what if there is data from D4 : G7... how can i shift the datas same with the previous one.. :)

Comment: @JayFronteras - I'm 99% positive it'll work just the same, just do `Set rng = Range("D4:G7")` and see if that does it.

Comment: yes it did work but I noticed that the right most datas entered of cells D5:D7 remains as i clicked the add new button, I was thinking how to remove this..

Comment: @JayFronteras - Ah, okay. I've edited the code, see if this works for you.

Comment: yeah bruce it perfectly worked! :) my only problem now is the down borders of the cells d4:d7 gets cleared also... :)

Comment: @JayFronteras - I think a quick fix for that is to do `rng.Offset(0,1).Value = rng.Value` and then I think it just should move the values, and leave the formatting alone. If it still does that, then also try `rng.Item(x).Value = ""`

Comment: works great @BruceWayne! the second code did the work... thanks very much for your effort! I don't know how to say thanks more than how I felt today.. You're legend man :)

Comment: I have another problem,when I try to increase the number of cells in the sheet, the datas entered on some cells remains.. I am not able to fix this one, hmm.. ![Valid XHTML] (http://www.imgur.com/Lw5eygL)